# Error installing Heroku Toolbelt to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, vagrant

When i installing Heroku Toolbelt to Ubuntu (it stands on VM on Vagrant) i have this errors:

```
Unpacking heroku-toolbelt (from .../heroku-toolbelt_3.12.1_all.deb) ...
dpkg-deb: file `/var/cache/apt/archives/heroku-toolbelt_3.12.1_all.deb' contains ununderstood data member data.tar.xz     , giving up
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/heroku-toolbelt_3.12.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/heroku-toolbelt_3.12.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I used cmd `wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

Answer (score 1):

This error appears because the version of dpkg that is available is < 1.15.6 and thus doesn't support xz compression used in the packaging of heroku-toolbelt.

Thankfully, heroku-toolbelt is a meta-package which doesn't install any tools but depends on the packages which provide the tools needed to interact with heroku.com's services!  Namely, heroku-toolbelt depends on:
git-core, foreman, heroku

So far none of these dependencies use xz compression, so I have successfully installed them and used the tools to access heroku.com's services.  I removed heroku-toolbelt so I don't get new installation errors every time an update is available.  The important packages--git-core, foreman, and heroku--still get automatic updates as available.